# How do you escape an Apostrophe in R so you can insert the string into a MySQL table

Tags: mysql, r, mariadb, tidyverse

I'm inserting some strings into a MYSQL table via an R script.  Some of the strings include apostrophes that need to be escaped prior to inserting into the table.

Given the following string:

```
myStr <- "AIN'T NO ELMERS"
```

I have tried the following alternatives with no luck:

str_replace(horse,'(\w+)(’)(.*)','\1\\\2\3'))   ==> results in an error message

str_replace(horse,'(\w+)(\’)(.*)','\1\\\2\3'))  ==> no error but the inserted string is AINâ€™T NO ELMERS

How does one escape successfully escape the apostrophe in the string?

My r script takes the following form:

```
library(DBI)
library(odbc)
library(RMariaDB)

insert <- dbSendQuery(con, "INSERT ignore INTO names(`name`, `value`) VALUES (?, ?)")
dbBind(insert, names)
dbClearResult(insert)
con <- dbDisconnect(con)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usual way to escape single apostrophes on the MySQL side is to just double them up, i.e. use `''`.  So try this version:

```r
myStr <- "AIN''T NO ELMERS"
```

Comment: When I do what you propose from with MySQL workbench it works like a charm, but when I run it from my r script I get this â€™ instead of the apostrophe

Comment: I've also confirmed that the database, table, and column character set is utf8, but I continue to get â€™ instead of the apostrophe.

Comment: How are you determining this?  Do you see the `â€™` when querying directly from MySQL or when you query from your R script?

Comment: I was seeing the â€™ after I ran my r script that inserted into the MYSQL table and then going into MySQL Workbench and querying to table I inserted into.  Once I set the character set using dbSendQuery(con, 'set character set "utf8"') it worked as expected without me having to escape the apostrophe.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved by ensuring the utf8 character set was utilized.

As a first step, use the following commands in your MYSQL database to ensure the database, table and columns are using utf8:

```
USE dbname;  SELECT @@character_set_database;
SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM dbname.tablename;
```

You can alter database, table and colunms with ALTER

```
ALTER TABLE `dbname`.`tablename` 
CHANGE COLUMN `colname` `colname` VARCHAR(10) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' NULL DEFAULT NULL ;
```

Next, use the following commands to ensure your insert statement is also utilizing utf8:

```
con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), "MySQL")
dbSendQuery(con, 'set character set "utf8"')
```

With this, apostrophes should be inserted into your table correctly.

Comment: The alternative might be to change R's character set used for accessing the MySQL API to match whatever your MySQL table/database were using.